# Encoding json from recursively merged php array

Tags: php, arrays, json, encode

I'm trying to make a `.json` file from a simple `mysqli_query`. I've tried this:

```
$res=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM Teams");
$i=0;
while ($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
  $jshteam[$i]=$row['shteam'];
  $jbyteam[$i]=$row['byteam'];
  $jcountry[$i]=$row['country'];
  $arrteams[$i]= array("".$jshteam[$i].""=>"country"=>"".$jcountry[$i]."","byteam"=>"".$jbyteam[$i].""]);    
  $i++;
}
$json_data= json_encode(array_merge_recursive($arrteams));
file_put_contents('json/teams.json', $json_data);
```

When doing this, the result of `teams.json` is as follows (first two elements):

```
[{"TEA":{"country":"Turkey","byteam":"TeamName1"}},{"VIS":{"country":"Germany","byteam":"TeamName2"}}]
```

I don't like the `[]` things at the beggining and at the end of the string. If I change this line of my code as follows:

```
$json_data= json_encode(array_merge_recursive($arrteams[0],$arrteams[1]));
file_put_contents('json/teams.json', $json_data);
```

... then I get exactly what I want:

```
{"TEA":{"country":"Turkey","byteam":"TeamName1"},"VIS":{"country":"Germany","byteam":"TeamName2"}}
```

The problem is that I can't make the `array_merge_recursive`manually, as in the second form, because I don't know how many results come from the query. It would be like:

```
$json_data= json_encode(array_merge_recursive($arrteams[0],$arrteams[1],$arrteams[2]....$arrteams[?] ));
```

How would you do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to create element like that, it mean you just need to merge the `array` inside looping. Here I give a sample code you can implement

```
$data = [];
while ($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    .
    .
    .
    .
    $data = array_merge($data, $arrteams[$i]);
    $i++;
}

$json_data= json_encode($data);
```

But, you must consider when `arrays` have same key (`eg: VIS, TEA`), `array_merge()` will override the existing array.

Answer (score 2):

I dont think you need array at all. I made this mock of your data stream and encoding :

```
$arr  = [];
$rows = [
    ["jsteam" => "TEA" , "byteam" => "TeamName1" , "country" => "Germany"] ,
    ["jsteam" => "VIS" , "byteam" => "TeamName2" , "country" => "Finland"]
];
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $jsteam          = $row["jsteam"];
    $byteam          = $row["byteam"];
    $country         = $row["country"];
    $arr [ $jsteam ] = ["country" => $country , "byteam" => $byteam];
}

$json = json_encode($arr , JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
$log->info("\n$json");
```

to get this in the log :

```
2017-06-27T04:08:16-04:00 cli.TestSomething INFO  
{
    "TEA": {
        "country": "Germany",
        "byteam": "TeamName1"
    },
    "VIS": {
        "country": "Finland",
        "byteam": "TeamName2"
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't even need `$byteam` and `$country`. You can do `unset($row['jsteam']);` (optional) then `$arr[$jsteam] = $row;`. A good answer, nevertheless.

Comment: Thank you. I accept the answer by Dolly Aswin as it is more close to what I was looking for. Your answer is still very good and useful.